# Google Analytics code says it's not being tracked

Tags: google-analytics, seo

Here is my website, [HSOTO](https://hsoto.me/), I followed the instructions that Google Analytics say, pasted the generated script just before the `</head>`, but on my dashboard in google analytics, it says it's not installed.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the .js files from Google are correctly loaded. If they are and you used the API keys provided when you added your site in Analytics, you should wait at least 24 hours for data to start collecting.

Comment: It's not mmediately? I added the script, and it loads the `<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>` correctly. It has my User key correctly installed as well on the script I had to copy. I have to wait some more time then?

Comment: Maybe if you check the real-time data section of Analytics, but for the rest of the site's aggregated data, it is collated only daily.

Comment: Thanks! The real time data section indeed told me there's quite a few visitors. Thanks!